# Project Euler: primes in Python

Tags: python, programming-challenge, primes

This is a Python module I have just finished writing which I plan to use at Project Euler.  Please let me know how I have done and what I could do to improve it.

```
# This constant is more or less an overestimate for the range in which
# n primes exist.  Generally 100 primes exist well within 100 * CONST numbers.
CONST = 20

def primeEval(limit):
    ''' This function yields primes using the
    Sieve of Eratosthenes.

    '''
    if limit:
        opRange = [True] * limit
        opRange[0] = opRange[1] = False

        for (ind, primeCheck) in enumerate(opRange):
            if primeCheck:
                yield ind
                for i in range(ind*ind, limit, ind):
                    opRange[i] = False

def listToNthPrime(termin):
    ''' Returns a list of primes up to the nth
    prime.
    '''
    primeList = []
    for i in primeEval(termin * CONST):
        primeList.append(i)
        if len(primeList) >= termin:
            break
    return primeList

def nthPrime(termin):
    ''' Returns the value of the nth prime.

    '''
    primeList = []
    for i in primeEval(termin * CONST):
        primeList.append(i)
        if len(primeList) >= termin:
            break
    return primeList[-1]

def listToN(termin):
    ''' Returns a list of primes up to the
    number termin.
    '''
    return list(primeEval(termin))

def lastToN(termin):
    ''' Returns the prime which is both less than n
    and nearest to n.

    '''
    return list(primeEval(termin))[-1]
```

Comment: It is a good idea to always follow PEP-0008 style guidolines: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: See [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/42439/11728).

Answer (score 2):

```
# This constant is more or less an overestimate for the range in which
# n primes exist.  Generally 100 primes exist well within 100 * CONST numbers.
CONST = 20

def primeEval(limit):
```

Python convention says that functions should named lowercase_with_underscores

```
    ''' This function yields primes using the
    Sieve of Eratosthenes.

    '''
    if limit:
```

What is this for? You could be trying to avoid erroring out when limit=0, but it seems to me that you still error at for limit=1.

```
        opRange = [True] * limit
```

As with functions, lowercase_with_underscore

```
        opRange[0] = opRange[1] = False

        for (ind, primeCheck) in enumerate(opRange):
```

You don't need the parens around `ind, primeCheck`

```
            if primeCheck:
                yield ind
                for i in range(ind*ind, limit, ind):
                    opRange[i] = False


def listToNthPrime(termin):
    ''' Returns a list of primes up to the nth
    prime.
    '''
    primeList = []
    for i in primeEval(termin * CONST):
        primeList.append(i)
        if len(primeList) >= termin:
            break
    return primeList
```

You are actually probably losing out by attempting to stop the generator once you pass the number you wanted. You could write this as:

```
 return list(primeEval(termin * CONST))[:termin]
```

Chances are that you gain more by having the loop be in the loop function than you gain by stopping early.

```
def nthPrime(termin):
    ''' Returns the value of the nth prime.

    '''
    primeList = []
    for i in primeEval(termin * CONST):
        primeList.append(i)
        if len(primeList) >= termin:
            break
    return primeList[-1]

def listToN(termin):
    ''' Returns a list of primes up to the
    number termin.
    '''
    return list(primeEval(termin))

def lastToN(termin):
    ''' Returns the prime which is both less than n
    and nearest to n.

    '''
    return list(primeEval(termin))[-1]
```

All of your functions will recalculate all the primes. For any sort of practical use you'll want to avoid that and keep the primes you've calculated.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I just omit the loop within the functions nthPrime and listToNthPrime, or that I change the function primeEval to include a parameter which will allow it to terminate early?  I just tested the calling functions without the loop.  I was surprised the loop provides only 3% increase in speed.  Also, what do you mean by "keep primes you've calculated"?

Comment: @JackJ, I'm suggesting you omit the loop. By keeping the primes, I mean that you should run sieve of erasthones once to find all the primes you need and use that data over and over again.

Comment: @JackJ, store it in a variable.

Comment: Sorry, but how would I reuse that data? By saving the output of the sieve to a file?  Also, is the reason for omitting the loop to increase readability?

Answer (score 1):

General programming issues (non-Python specific):

- **Avoiding duplicated code:** `listToNthPrime()` and `nthPrime()` are identical beside the indexing. The later could be changed to `def nthprime(termin): return listToNthPrime(termin)[-1]`. But it can be argued if such a function is needed anyway, because indexing the first or last element of lists is such a basic usage that usually no further abstraction is necessary. So you could just replace you calls to `nthPrime()` by `listToNthPrime()[-1]`. The same is obviously also valid for `listToN()` and `lastToN()` in both senses. In fact you can just omit these functions.
- **Naming:** all identifier names should catch its purpose according to the abstraction level as precise they can (resulting clunky names are usually showing a need to refactor / change the abstraction). In that sense the name `primeEval` could be improved. "Eval" often is just too general to be really meaningful. `iterPrimes()` will work. Further it makes it clear that it is no list.