# Sum of primes program is taking too long

Tags: python, performance, primes

I don't understand what is taking the program so long:

```
#!/bin/python

primes=[]
i=0
j=0
k=0

for i in range(2,2000000): #fill in the list
    primes.append(i)

i=0
while i<len(primes):
    j=primes[i]
    print(j)
    k=0
    while j*(j+k)<primes[len(primes)-1]: ##referred as 'line A'
        try:
            primes.remove(j*(j+k))
        except ValueError:
           k=k+1
           continue
        k=k+1
    i=i+1

sump=0
i=0
for i in range(len(primes)):
    sump=sump+primes[i]

print(sump)
```

I understand why the overall code is very inefficient, but line A takes 2 hours for `j=2`, and I don't understand why that is. Surely the `list.remove(x)` method is very inefficient?

Comment: There is a lot you can do to improve performances in this script. The first for loop can be replaced with `primes = list(range(2,2000000))`, `primes[len(primes)-1]` is `primes[-1]` and the last for loop is `sump = sum(primes)`. I don't think that's your problem, but it's a start.

Comment: Is this Python 2? Have you done any profiling before asking?

Comment: Try moving the value of len(primes) into a variable and use that in the while loop. And try modifying the expression to "j*(j+k)" to "j*j + j * k" where "j*j" is pre calculated and put into some variable which would be used in computing the value of the expression

Comment: Tight loops are not exactly Python strongest point. Removing the inner loop with an equivalent idiomatic construct would improve things a lot. Eg. `primes = [x for x in primes if x % j or x == j]`. Even creating a completely new list each loop, this is orders of magnitude faster

Comment: @Wooble This is python 3 and I don't know what profiling is

Comment: sump = n**2 * math.log(n) / 2

Comment: Anyway, yes, `list.remove` is an O(n) operation; first it needs to search through the list to find the item, then move all of the items after it in the list one spot to the left. Using a set would be much more efficient.

Comment: list.remove() is expensive, and you don't need it. If you keep your `primes` list intact, you know exactly where to find `j*(j+k)` -- it is at index `j*(j+k) - 2`. You can just set that element to zero, and then ignore zero elements in your `sump` loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe it is actually the specific `Lne A` that is the problem, but everything that is happening inside that loop, and most importantly, the line: `primes.remove(...)`. From [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521784/cost-of-list-functions-in-python) you can see that remove(...) is an *O(n)* operation, thus it's performance is relative to the amount of data in the array. In this case, there's a lot.... and you are doing a lot of `removes()` since you are essentially removing all even values except `2`.

What you should be doing is using a more efficient algorithm. You should read up on the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), and introduce that algorithm here.

it will be much faster because it does not do any array-size changes. There are a number of posts here on CodeReview that have this problem solved quite nicely:

- [Sieve of Eratosthenes: making it quicker](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6477/sieve-of-eratosthenes-making-it-quicker)
- [Project Euler: primes in Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21659/criticize-my-first-python-module-please)

([Primes in Python...](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D%20Eratosthenes))

([Sieve in other languages](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=is:question%20Sieve%20Eratosthenes))

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful (: This was actually a (failed) implementation of Sieves of Eratosthenes. I see that the list.remove method isn't the right thing to use, thanks!