# Sieve of Eratosthenes - Python

Tags: python, performance, primes, python-3.x, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I've been doing a lot of Project Euler lately and just wanted to make sure my implementation was as good as it could be. Does anyone have any suggestions to speed this up?

```
def sieve(upperlimit):
    # mark off all multiples of 2 so we can use 2*p as the step for the inner loop
    l = [2] + [x if x % 2 != 0 else 0 for x in range(3, upperlimit + 1)]

    for p in l:
        if p ** 2 > upperlimit:
            break
        elif p:
            for i in range(p * p, upperlimit + 1, 2 * p):
                l[i - 2] = 0
    # filter out non primes from the list, not really that important i could work with a list full of zeros as well
    return [x for x in l if x]
```

Answer (score 34):

1. Here's my starting point for computing the performance improvement due to the various revisions below: how long does it take to sieve for the prime numbers below \$ 10^8 \$?

   ```
   >>> from timeit import timeit
   >>> test = lambda f: timeit(lambda:f(10**8), number=1)
   >>> t1 = test(sieve)
   ```

   The exact number is going to depend on how fast your computer is, so I'm going to compute performance ratios, but for the record, here it is:

   ```
   >>> t1
   78.9875438772142
   ```
2. Your initialization of the list `l` takes more than half the time, so let's try a cheaper approach. Let's also give this array a better name, and make it a Boolean array while we're about it.

   ```
   def sieve2(n):
       """Return a list of the primes below n."""
       prime = [True] * n
       for p in range(3, n, 2):
           if p ** 2 > n:
               break
           if prime[p]:
               for i in range(p * p, n, 2 * p):
                   prime[i] = False
       return [2] + [p for p in range(3, n, 2) if prime[p]]
   ```

   When optimizing a function like this, it's always worth keeping the un-optimized version around to check the correctness of the optimized version:

   ```
   >>> sieve(10**6) == sieve2(10**6)
   True
   ```

   This already runs in less than a third of the time:

   ```
   >>> test(sieve2) / t1
   0.30390444573149544
   ```
3. We could avoid the test for `p ** 2 > n` by computing a tighter limit for the loop. Note that I've used `n ** .5` here as this is slightly faster than `math.sqrt(n)`.

   ```
   def sieve3(n):
       """Return a list of the primes below n."""
       prime = [False, False, True] + [True, False] * (n // 2)
       for p in range(3, int(n ** .5) + 1, 2):
           if prime[p]:
               for i in range(p * p, n, 2 * p):
                   prime[i] = False
       return [p for p in range(2, n) if prime[p]]
   ```

   This makes little difference to the overall runtime:

   ```
   >>> test(sieve3) / t1
   0.2971086436068156
   ```
4. We can accumulate the result as we go, instead of in a separate iteration at the end. Note that I've cached `result.append` in a local variable to avoid looking it up each time round the loop.

   ```
   def sieve4(n):
       """Return a list of the primes below n."""
       prime = [False, False, True] + [True, False] * (n // 2)
       result = [2]
       append = result.append
       sqrt_n = (int(n ** .5) + 1) | 1    # ensure it's odd
       for p in range(3, sqrt_n, 2):
           if prime[p]:
               append(p)
               for i in range(p * p, n, 2 * p):
                   prime[i] = False
       for p in range(sqrt_n, n, 2):
           if prime[p]:
               append(p)
       return result
   ```

   Again, this makes very little difference:

   ```
   >>> test(sieve4) / t1
   0.286016401170129
   ```
5. We can use Python's slice assignment instead of a loop when setting the sieve entries to `False`. This looks wasteful since we create a large list and then throw it away, but this avoids an expensive `for` loop and the associated Python interpreter overhead.

   ```
   def sieve5(n):
       """Return a list of the primes below n."""
       prime = [True] * n
       result = [2]
       append = result.append
       sqrt_n = (int(n ** .5) + 1) | 1    # ensure it's odd
       for p in range(3, sqrt_n, 2):
           if prime[p]:
               append(p)
               prime[p*p::2*p] = [False] * ((n - p*p - 1) // (2*p) + 1)
       for p in range(sqrt_n, n, 2):
           if prime[p]:
               append(p)
       return result
   ```

   This gives a small but noticeable improvement:

   ```
   >>> test(sieve5) / t1
   0.2617646381557855
   ```
6. For big improvements to the performance of numerical code, we can use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/).

   ```
   import numpy

   def sieve6(n):
       """Return an array of the primes below n."""
       prime = numpy.ones(n, dtype=numpy.bool)
       prime[:2] = False
       prime[4::2] = False
       sqrt_n = int(n ** .5) + 1
       for p in range(3, sqrt_n, 2):
           if prime[p]:
               prime[p*p::2*p] = False
       return prime.nonzero()[0]
   ```

   This is more than 6 times as fast as `sieve5`, and more than 25 times as fast as your original code:

   ```
   >>> test(sieve6) / t1
   0.03726392181902129
   ```
7. We could avoid allocating space for the even numbers, improving memory locality:

   ```
   def sieve7(n):
       """Return an array of the primes below n."""
       prime = numpy.ones(n // 2, dtype=numpy.bool)
       sqrt_n = int(n ** .5) + 1
       for p in range(3, sqrt_n, 2):
           if prime[p // 2]:
               prime[p*p // 2::p] = False
       result = 2 * prime.nonzero()[0] + 1
       result[0] = 2
       return result
   ```

   ```
   >>> test(sieve7) / t1
   0.029220096670965198
   ```
8. And finally, an implementation that sieves separately for primes of the form \$ 6i − 1 \$ and \$ 6i + 1 \$, [due to Robert William Hanks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/68063):

   ```
   def sieve8(n):
       """Return an array of the primes below n."""
       prime = numpy.ones(n//3 + (n%6==2), dtype=numpy.bool)
       for i in range(3, int(n**.5) + 1, 3):
           if prime[i // 3]:
               p = (i + 1) | 1
               prime[       p*p//3     ::2*p] = False
               prime[p*(p-2*(i&1)+4)//3::2*p] = False
       result = (3 * prime.nonzero()[0] + 1) | 1
       result[0] = 3
       return numpy.r_[2,result]
   ```

   This is about 40 times as fast as the original `sieve`:

   ```
   >>> test(sieve8) / t1
   0.023447068662434022
   ```

Comment: 7 can be generalized using wheel factorization, which gets you another large improvement. Filling the sieve in chunks that fit into L1 or L2 cache gets another factor 5 or more according to my experience

Comment: @NiklasB.: Sounds interesting! Can you post your code?

Comment: @GarethRees: I wrote an implementation of it for an online judge problem once: http://pastie.org/8758862 It computes π(10^9) in under a second on my machine, but bear with me, it's highly optimized and dead ugly... It also contains some other custom optimizations than the ones I mentioned if I remember correctly. Nice job on that numpy implementation, it's blazingly fast. I guess I overestimated the speedup you can get over that. Really cool

Answer (score 10):

Your first setting of all the even numbers to 0 is not very efficient, the whole point of sieving is to avoid those costly modulo operations. Try the following:

```
l = range(2, upperlimit+1) # use list(range(...)) in Python 3
l[2::2] = [0] * ((len(l) - 3) // 2 + 1)
```

You can do a similar thing for the setting of zeros of the sieve for other prime numbers, but it gets complicated to figure out how many zeros to add on the right.

Comment: Oh nice catch, yea that saved me a decent chunk of time when generating the list

Comment: Note that this fails in python3 (and the question is tagged python3).

Comment: Yep, Python 3 requires wrapping the `range` in a `list` for it to work, added it as a comment above.

Answer (score 7):

You have correctly implemented the optimization `p ** 2 > upperlimit`, but, there is a more efficient way to do it...

`p ** 2 > upperlimit` calculates the square of `p` for every iteration through the loop. The product is not hugely expensive, but it is also totally unnecessary....

You can calculate the square-root of the upperlimit just once, and then reuse that calculated value as a direct comparison for `p`. Consider:

```
rootlimit = math.sqrt(upperlimit)
for p in l:
    if p > rootlimit:
        break;
    ....
```

Additionally, it is a small thing, but if you have `break`, `continue`, or `return`, inside a conditional inside a loop, then there is no need to use `elif`... It is just a small thing, but your code could be:

```
rootlimit = math.sqrt(upperlimit)
for p in l:
    if p > rootlimit:
        break;
    if p:
        ....
```

Answer (score 7):

```
for p in l:
    if p ** 2 > upperlimit:
        break
    elif p:
        ...
```

In this loop `p` is often zero, while `p ** 2 > upperlimit` is always false until the `break`. That means you evaluate both conditions always. If you put `if p:` first, only one condition is evaluated whenever `p` is not prime.