# Wheel based unbounded sieve of Eratosthenes in Python

Tags: python, performance, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Answering [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30553925/849891) recently, I've developed the following code (based on a well-known Active Code recipe, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733621)):

```
wheel = [2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,6,6,2,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,2,4,2,
         4,8,6,4,6,2,4,6,2,6,6,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,2,10,2,10]
wsize = 48

def primes(): 
    yield from (2, 3, 5, 7)
    yield from wsieve()

def wsieve():       # wheel-sieve, by Will Ness. cf. ideone.com/WFv4f
    yield 11        # cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733621/849891     
    mults = {}      #     https://stackoverflow.com/a/19391111/849891
    ps = wsieve() 
    p = next(ps)   
    psq, c, i = p*p, 11, 0                   # 13 = 11 + wheel[0]
    cbase, ibase = 11, 0  
    while True:
        c += wheel[i] ; i = (i+1) % wsize    # 17 = 13 + wheel[1]
        if c in mults:
            (j,pbase) = mults.pop(c)         # add(mults, NEXT c, j, pbase)
        elif c < psq:              
            yield c ; continue   
        else:          # (c==psq)       
            while not cbase == p:
                cbase += wheel[ibase]
                ibase = (ibase+1) % wsize    # ibase - initial offset into wheel, for p
            j, pbase = ibase, p              # add(mults, NEXT c, ibase, p)
            p = next(ps) ; psq = p*p
        m = c + pbase*wheel[j] ; j = (j+1) % wsize    # mults(p) = map (*p)
        while m in mults:                             #              roll(wheel,ibase,p)
            m += pbase*wheel[j] ; j = (j+1) % wsize    
        mults[m] = (j,pbase)
```

Comparing its performance [on ideone](http://ideone.com/nw1BQn) with [its odds-based predecessor](http://ideone.com/WFv4f) reveals it runs about *1.5x* faster. Empirical complexity seems okay (*~ n<sup>1.1</sup>*, for *n* primes produced).

Theoretically, it's supposed to be `1 / (2/3 * 4/5 * 6/7) =` *2.1875x* times faster, if I'm not mistaken (indeed, taking ratio of circumference over number of teeth, `(210/48) / (2/1) = 2.1875`).  But it is slower than that.

Is this just because of the increased code complexity? Is there a way to make it run faster, without changing it drastically? Improve it in some other sense, or make it prettier/more pythonic without loosing performance? Will appreciate a review.

In particular, I have the rolled wheel streams inlined, using different variables for different "objects". It seems all over the place; is there a way to encapsulate it into a bona fide object, without loosing performance? ([last time](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1a189252-9dfd-4b13-9dee-4dae2e03b98a/view-source) when I used functions for some encapsulation, [efficiency suffered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19391111/849891)).

Comment: FWIW: **PyPy**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I thought of two things that achieve a 27 % speedup and simplify `wsieve` a bit, at the expense of some precomputations.

- Turning the wheel step by step from prime to prime seems wasteful. Instead of this code

  ```
  while not cbase == p:
      cbase += wheel[ibase]
      ibase = (ibase+1) % wsize   
  j = ibase
  ```

  you could do directly `j = spoke_index[p % 210]` having precomputed a suitable `spoke_index` dictionary with 48 entries. The variables `cbase` and `ibase` can be eliminated.
- When a wheel is involved I find it hard to resist using [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle). Instead of this

  ```
  i = 0                   
  while True:
      c += wheel[i] ; i = (i+1) % wsize
  ```

  you could do this

  ```
  for step in cycle(wheel):
      c += step
  ```

  The other uses of the wheel are more difficult to replace because there is no direct way to start the cycle at an arbitrary position. However, we can precompute all 48 rotations of `wheels` and put them in a dictionary for easy lookup.

My version of full solution. Instead of the index `j` I put a cyclic iterator in `mults`.

```
from itertools import cycle

CIRCUMFERENCE = 2*3*5*7
BASE_PRIMES = (2,3,5,7)
NEXT_PRIME = 11

def wheel(start):
    result = []
    i = start
    for j in range(i + 1, i + 1 + CIRCUMFERENCE):
        if all(j % k for k in BASE_PRIMES):
            result.append(j - i)
            i = j
    return result

def rotated_wheels():
    result = {}
    i = 1
    while i < CIRCUMFERENCE:
        result[i] = wheel(i)
        i = i + result[i][0]
    return result

def primes(): 
    yield from BASE_PRIMES
    yield from wsieve()

def wsieve(wheels=rotated_wheels()):       
    yield NEXT_PRIME          
    mults = {}      
    ps = wsieve() 
    p = next(ps)   
    psq, c = p*p, p             
    cwheel = cycle(wheels[c])
    for step in cwheel:
        c += step
        if c in mults:
            (mwheel, pbase) = mults.pop(c)         
        elif c < psq:              
            yield c 
            continue   
        else:          # (c==psq)     
            mwheel = cycle(wheels[p % CIRCUMFERENCE])
            pbase = p             
            p = next(ps) ; psq = p*p
        m = c
        for mstep in mwheel:
            m += pbase * mstep
            if m not in mults:
                break
        mults[m] = (mwheel, pbase)
```

---

Edited to use `for` instead of `while`.

Comment: the start index on the wheel for a prime `p` should be `(p-11) % 210`, more or less. I thought turning the wheel is nice, conceptually, as it finds the intersection of coprimes (zipped with the wheel position) and primes; and the primes are found as set difference of coprimes and multiples of primes. it has a nice math quality about it (see the last entry [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers_miscellaneous#One-liners)). :) also, since it's going at the sqrt pace, it shouldn't have contributed that much to the run time, I thought... `cycle` is exactly the kind of idea I was hoping for.

Comment: using itertools tools may increase  speed because they are working "on the C side" presumably.

Comment: @WillNess Well if you prefer to turn the wheel, you can use `cycle(enumerate(wheel))` as the iterator.

Comment: following your advice, using itertools I was able to streamline the code some more and achieve [a speedup of 11%](http://ideone.com/trR9OI)! Thank you.

Comment: (18% actually...)

Answer (score 4):

How long does your code take to find the first million primes (that is, all the primes below 15,485,864)?

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda:list(islice(primes(), 10**6)), number=1)
5.053490979000344
```

Compared to the implementations in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/42439/11728), this is faster than `sieve` but slower than `sieve2`:

```
>>> timeit(lambda:list(sieve(15485864)), number=1)
10.124665475999791
>>> timeit(lambda:list(sieve2(15485864)), number=1)
3.4201999040014925
```

Even though these implementations ought to be asympotically worse.

The trouble with implementing this kind of algorithm in Python is that the big overhead of the Python interpreter tends to overwhelm small algorithmic improvements, if those improvements mean that you end up spending more time in the slow Python bytecode and less time in the fast C implementation.

#### Update

There's some confusion in comments about what I mean by "asympotically worse" above. The complexity of sieving for primes below \$n\$ is $$ C n \log \log n + O(1) $$ for some constant \$C\$. Wheel sieving using the first \$k\$ primes theoretically saves a factor of $$ \prod_{i\le k}{p_i-1\over p_i},$$ so wheel sieving with 2 should halve the runtime; with 2 and 3 it should reduce the runtime to a third, and so on. This is a constant factor of improvement, so it wouldn't appear in the big-O analysis (it would get folded into the constant \$C\$). But in real life, constant factors matter too: effectively in your code you are exchanging a larger number of cheap operations for a smaller number of expensive operations. With a large-enough wheel, you ought to be able to beat the naïve algorithms. But it might have to be quite large.

Comment: [1M    5.10s-8.7MB](http://ideone.com/nw1BQn) on ideone.

Comment: I wonder whether the unrolling could help - like shown in your linked answer's #8. It allows for constant step again. Maybe for the smaller wheel, with 30-circumference and only 8 teeth... will have to try it sometime.

Comment: The key to the performance of `sieve8` is that it does very little in the Python interpreter: by careful computation of indexes it manages to dispatch nearly all the work to NumPy, where numeric operations on arrays are cheap.

Answer (score 1):

Using itertools after the advice from Janne Karila (big  thanks!), I got a whopping [1.5x speedup](http://ideone.com/trR9OI) with the following streamlined, and dare I say, altogether canonical-looking code,

```
def wsieve():       # wheel-sieve, by Will Ness.    ideone.com/mqO25A->0hIE89
    wh11 = [ 2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,6,6, 2,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,2,4,2,
             4,8,6,4,6,2,4,6,2,6,6,4, 2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,2,10,2,10]
    cs = accumulate( chain( [11], cycle( wh11)))
    yield( next( cs))       #   cf. ideone.com/WFv4f
    ps = wsieve()           #     codereview.stackexchange.com/q/92365/9064
    p = next(ps)            # 11
    psq = p*p               # 121
    D = dict( zip( accumulate( chain( [0], wh11)), count(0)))   # start from
    sieve = {}
    for c in cs:
        if c in sieve:
            wheel = sieve.pop(c)  
            for m in wheel: 
                if not m in sieve: 
                    break
            sieve[m] = wheel    # sieve[143] = wheel@187
        elif c < psq:              
            yield c  
        else:          # (c==psq)   
            # map (p*) (roll wh from p) = roll (wh*p) from (p*p)
            x = [p*d for d in wh11]
            i = D[ (p-11) % 210]
            wheel = accumulate( chain( [psq], cycle( x[i:] + x[:i])))
            p = next(ps) ; psq = p*p
            next(wheel) ; m = next(wheel)
            sieve[m] = wheel
```

*a later note:* an attempt at [unrolling it](https://ideone.com/sQC27a) didn't pan out, ran at ~20% slower.

Comment: Answer converted to community wiki.

Comment: Is there a way I can make this yield 2,3,5, and 7 before it starts? doing so the obvious way breaks everything.

Comment: @OscarSmith just create another generator that yields 2,3,5,7, and then calls `wsieve`. It's already defined in the question itself, as `def primes()`.